# python pandas - turn the name of a pandas series into a value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a serie that is as follow:

```
MFE_ts            2000-02-01 02:30:00
MAE_pr                        1400.75
MAE_ts             949383000000000000
MAE                               1.5
netgain_by_MAE                1.33333
Name: 2000-02-01 02:30:00, dtype: object
```

I would like to turn the name of the serie into a value and to give a new name to the serie to achieve a result such as :

```
exit_time         2000-02-01 02:30:00
MFE_ts            2000-02-01 02:30:00
MAE_pr                        1400.75
MAE_ts             949383000000000000
MAE                               1.5
netgain_by_MAE                1.33333
Name: entry_time, dtype: object
```

How could I achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing `s` is your series, you can achieve it like this:

```
s['exit_time'] = s.name
s.name = 'entry_time'
```

Comment: thx that seems to be working!
however the name of the serie that use to be `2000-02-01 02:30:00` is now returned as something like `9.493722e+17` 
How can i maintain the proper formatting for it?

Comment: @jimbasquiat I figured out a way to fix it by calling `s['exit_time'] = s.name` one more time. The issue is that when `'exit_time'` is not an existing index, some type conversion will happen. I still don't understand this behavior. I'll try to dig it out.

Comment: Yes it did work - Yes i dont know how to assign a datetime datatype to an empty/new column. I've had that problem in the past.. still dont know how to do. Let me know if you find the solution

Comment: @jim-basquiat I found the same question asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40716361/python-pandas-series-failure-datetime). But there's no answer yet. In the comment EdChum says it might be a bug in pandas.